# How to open a heavy html file

Tags: html

I have recently downloaded my facebook archive, which is a very old account I started in 2009.

There is some conversations I would like to read, the main problem is that messages.html inside the zip weights 98 mo.

Unfortunately,neither mozilla or google chrome can open those 21109 lines of codes in a webview without crashing.

I could open the document with Notepad++, but it's just like searching for a needle in a haystack.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: What is it you are looking for?  BTW - You know Facebook's API is pretty open and you should be able to leverage it to look for specific information.  Unfortunately, you don't give us much to work with.

Comment: Have a try using a text based browser like `links` or `lynx`. They require far less resources. But the usability of the display then depends very much on how the document is structured.

Comment: @Leptonator I have deleted the account long time ago, I only have the archive.
I'm sorry if I didn't give you much informations, do you think with Facebook's API I can open the archive like if I was using facebook ?

Comment: Look on http://superuser.com/questions/273777/how-to-open-a-huge-html-file or http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/187164-opening-huge-html-file-80mb.html The first link recommends some Linux shell tools.

Comment: @arkascha I tried links 2.12 64bits version, the browser stops to respond after 3 minutes.

Comment: @TheVanD That is impressive, never seen that. What is the exact size of the uncompressed document? What does "98 mo" mean? You might have to try to split the document into manageable chunks, either by means of a simple text editor, or, if that also fails (where I would expect that it is more your system that has an issue than the specific tool you use), by means of file based utilities like `split` or maybe sed/awk to keep the structure.

Comment: it's 98 mega bytes, 100 608 181 bytes and it's only one html file.
I don't have any options left, I have tried @Reeno suggestions by installing apache and load the html file from local but the page's content doesn't load after 2 minutes (without crashing this time).

I think I have no option left than rebuild the page into several parts by changing the html tags and divide it.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the LINUX comments, we  can only assume you are trying to look (or search) inside the html file.  You can use any good, text editor like: TextPad, EditPad, etc.  You can also download "[Unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)" (not it is not mis-spelled) and use the Windows ports of grep/sed/awk/head/tail/cut etc.  There maybe comments or answers posted to use Cygwin which work fine, but require the use of DLL libraries and such.  The UnxUtils are stand-alone exe files are work right out of the box with no installation required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in getting some readable files for each conversation you can use the first part of this tutorial which generates csv files which are easily searchable.

http://openmachin.es/blog/facebook-messages